# Pointer allocated in for: should I have to free it?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

Let's suppose I have this code:

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
  //compute z
  float *p = (float *) malloc (sizeof(float)*z);
  //do something with p
}
```

Notice that `p` isn't used anywhere else and each `for` cycle is independent from the other.

Let's suppose that `z` is not so big, so the *single* `p` is not that expensive in terms of memmory. However, `n` is potentially big, so the total memory taken by `p` can be consistent.

Is it correct to `free()` it with:

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
  //compute z
  float *p = (float *) malloc (sizeof(float)*z);
  //do something with p
  free(p);
}
```

**Bonus question:** if time performance would be the priority (and not memory consumption), would be better to avoid the `free(p)`, since it's time consuming?

Comment: Why is C++ tag here?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged this with **C++**, you should never use `malloc` and `free`. Use [**smart pointers**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) *(or `new`/`delete` if you don't have access to a C++11-compliant compiler)*.

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
  // compute z
  std::unique_ptr<float[]> p{new float[z]};
  // do something with p
  // p gets automatically freed at the end of the scope
}
```

---

*To answer your questions:*

> Is it correct to free() it with...

Yes. If you allocate something with `malloc`, you always need to `free` it.

> would be better to avoid the free(p), since it's time consuming?

Yes. Consider preallocating the memory location outside of the loop.

```
// preallocate
std::unique_ptr<float[]> p{new float[z]};

for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
  // clear p
  // compute z
  // do something with p
}

// p gets automatically freed at the end of the scope
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've never used smart pointers, but my question is: what appens if I do `v.push_back(p)` where `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<float[]>>` and I use `v` outside the `for` loop? `p` will be automatically freed at the end of the scope anyway?

Comment: If you use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<float[]>>`, you're defining a heap-allocated resizable array of heap-allocated arrays. You probably want `std::vector<float>` instead. I made a [video tutorial on smart pointers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMdD-s5_BIY) a while ago - I think it would be a good place to start if you enjoy learning through videos.

Answer (score 3):

You can pre-allocate necessary memory amount before the cycle and re-use it.

In case if you don't know how big `z` would be - I would recommend to write size of allocated memory somewhere, and if `z` is bigger than it - then re-allocate, else - just re-use already allocated memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `z` is highly variable, could few hundreds as hundreds of thousand (it's the number of keypoints detected by the SIFT algorithm, which totally depends on the input image).

Comment: then just re-allocate if Z is more than previous high Z, for which memory was already allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Observe: `malloc` is used. Act: invoke `free`. It's as simple as that. Portable, well-defined code requires `malloc` **and** `free`.

The amount of memory allocated plays no role here. If it's too much memory, `malloc` will throw an error, but that has nothing to do with the fact that you always need a `free` to follow a `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, if we're talking about an high performance application, `free` could be time consuming, so even if memory inefficient it could be more efficient in terms of time.

Comment: @justHelloWorld Don't strive for efficiency at the cost of correctness. If performance matters to you, pre-allocate memory and reuse it, just [as @Starl1ght said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40992293/3494013). In every case, call `free` after `malloc`. And if the amount of memory is ["highly variable"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992251/pointer-allocated-in-for-should-i-have-to-free-it/40992321#comment69193323_40992293) as you said, come up with a clever way to do it otherwise. Spot a pattern and think of some sneaky way, but don't forget dear Mr. `free`.

Comment: Roger that sir, I will not forget him :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You must `free` it.  Otherwise you have a memory leak, which is bad.  Especially if you loop a large number of times.

A good rule of thumb is that every `malloc` must be matched by a `free`.  Always.  (this is especially important on larger projects)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a buffer, that is reused in order to avoid unnecessary allocations. This can be done very easily by using `std::vector<float>`:

```
std::vector<float> p;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    //compute z
    p.resize( z );
    //do something with p
}
```

In the worst case you get `O(log n)` memory allocations. With your code you will get `n` memory allocations. Not calling `free()` just causes a memory leak. `std::vector<float>` will clean up the memory automatically eventually.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the size is constant, so why you want to allocate it again and again?
Just allocate once before the loop, inside the loop initialise at the beginning. 
You can reuse the memory. And after the loop ends free the memory.

And the program ends after the loop then you don't have to free it, all the heap memory that the program consumed would be returned to the OS, but it is always a good practice to free the memory you allocate.
On the bonus question, free is not that time consuming but allocating memory is, so don't worry on the time consumed by free.

Answer (score 0):

If you reuse that memory again - it is obviously more efficient to free it only when you end your program and only allocated it once (and reallocate using `realloc()` when you need bigger/smaller array).

Every OS you will probably program for will handle releasing dynamically allocated memory when your program terminates. But, as we mostly try to keep our code as cross-platform as possible, you should always `free()` dynamically allocated memory.

As for if you have a huge amount of memory and care only for speed - then obviously `free()`ing would 'slow down' the program, but the amount of time it takes is so ridiculously small, `76*(10**-8)` on my humble machine, for a 1024 bytes chunk, so it is fairly insignificant.